# Why do iPads require a third-party font manager App to install fonts?

Tags: ipad, font, ipados

Desktop operating systems like macOS, Windows or Ubuntu have some font management built-in to their file manager. If the user has some .ttf font files, they can simply double click or right click the files and install. This looks simple and intuitive.

This is not the case on the iPad. Even if you download a .ttf file from Safari, tapping it in the File App does not work. You have to use a third-party font manager App.

Why is there this difference between desktop operating systems and iPadOS?

Comment: Seems the iOS design is fairly easy : https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/install-and-manage-fonts-ipad952422ba/ipados

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asking why Apple does things is explicitly off topic here.

Comment: iOS is just different in all kinds of ways.  You can only get apps from the App Store. You can't make a custom keyboard.  If you want Apple to change it, let them know via http://www.apple.com/feedback

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing 'desktop' operating systems to mobile, which is not a straight comparison. macOS also allows simple double-click to install a font.

The root cause appears to be that on iOS/iPadOS fonts must be installed using a configuration profile. Fonts from the App Store appear to be already designed this way.
Installing your own fonts does not.

You can make config files for free on a Mac using Configurator 2, but there's no equivalent Windows app, so you'll need to use a 3rd party iOS/iPadOS config generator.

I imagine this is to make removal as simple as addition.

See
[Apple KB - Install and manage fonts on iPad](https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/ipad952422ba/ipados)
[HowToGeek - How to Install Fonts on an iPad or iPhone](https://www.howtogeek.com/350438/how-to-install-fonts-on-an-ipad-or-iphone/)
[HowToGeek - How to Create an iOS Configuration Profile and Alter Hidden Settings](https://www.howtogeek.com/253325/how-to-create-an-ios-configuration-profile-and-alter-hidden-settings/)

Answer (score -1):

This question is entirely about why Apple has chosen to do something and not something else - it cannot really be answered by anyone but the particular Apple employees involved in that decision.

However, if I were to guess about why it is done like this, I see two possible reasons:

**Reason 1:** The process of installing fonts from files in file managers on desktop operating systems is really not that intuitive for non-technical users.

You might think it is simple and intuitive for you, but I guarantee that I have seen lots of people struggle with this on Windows for example. Some fonts comes as lots of separate files (for various features such as italics, bold, black, thin, etc) and they often have non-descriptive names. People mess up and only get one file installed, or they miss one - or they cannot find the right font file because they can't match up the name of the file with the name of a font they're missing in Word or other software.

For businesses, it is also a project in itself to ensure that all employees have the right fonts installed in the right versions. If you want to be able to share internal documents, you have to ensure that everyone has the right fonts. The set of fonts might vary quite a lot depending on whether you're in sales & marketing, product development or customer support. And you do not want to have every employee spending time on installing them manually.

**Reason 2:** Right managements for fonts on desktop operating systems have always been problematic for the companies and individuals that create fonts. If you can just copy a TTF file to your colleague, it is very easy to violate a font licensing agreement without knowing - and without the licensor having much flexibility.

I.e. you typically do not see serial numbers or license codes used for fonts on desktop operating systems. For web typography, it's a completely different ball game, which can be very confusing to the licensee. I.e. you could be licensing a font for a specific domain only, for a certain number of "visits", or various odd limitations.

That font installation happens through a third party app on iOS makes this process simpler for both the licensee and the licensor (but obviously slightly more difficult for those that violate license agreements). The publisher of the app is contractually bound to actually have the rights for the fonts they're selling, and the licensee gets a familiar buying process with Apple that they're used to for apps.

Comment: I believe that 'security' may also be a factor.

Comment: The rights issue is nonsense.  The apps do not exercise any control over what fonts you can install, they just provide the mechanism for installing whatever you download from anyplace on the internet.

Comment: @TomGewecke It's not nonsense. You're talking about a very specific subset of these fonts app - namely those that allow the user to import any TTF (or similar format) font. I was talking in general - a lot of font apps are apps from the publishers of the font itself.